# Regular Grammar to my Regex/DFA

Tags: regex, grammar, dfa, chomsky-hierarchy

I have following regular expression: ((abc)+d)|(ef*g?)

I have created a DFA (I hope it is correct) which you can see here

http://www.informatikerboard.de/board/attachment.php?attachmentid=495&sid=f4a1d32722d755bdacf04614424330d2

The task is to create a regular grammar (Chomsky hierarchy Type 3) and I don't get it. But I created a regular grammar, which looks like this:

S → aT

T → b

T → c

T → dS

S → eT

S → eS

T → ε

T → f

T → fS

T → gS

Best Regards
Patrick

Comment: Isn't type 3 Chomsky exactly the class of the regular grammars allowing rules `A -> aA` and `A -> a` only? If so, this is already in Chomsky form...

Comment: I don't know, it is like I said: I don't get it... thats why I ask.

Comment: Your DFA is correct :) Don't be shy to use many non-terminals sometimes you'll need a lot to make a regex work.

Comment: My pleasure, you can thank me by accepting the answer and upvote (only) if you like it!

Comment: Important side note: the epsilon rule `S -> eps` can ONLY be a valid rule in type 3 Chomsky if the empty string is accepted by the regex!!

Comment: I've got another question, you choosed state names like S, T, U and so on... does it matter how these states are named? can I name them like I named my states in the DFA? it would look like this:

Z1 → aZ2 

Z2 → bZ3

Z3 → cZ4 

Z4 → cZ2

Z4 → dZ5
 
Z5 → ε

Z1 → eZ6
 
Z6 → ε

Z6 → fZ7

Z6 → gZ8

Z7 → ε

Z7 → fZ7

Z7 → gZ8

Z8 → ε

ε = Final / empty state?

Comment: You can name them however you like! Normally no mathematician would worry about semantics like that, as long as you're consistent!

Comment: Allright I got it. But in your example: V -> d

wouldn't it be correct to do it like this:

V -> dW
W -> ε 

Isn't ε a final state?

Comment: Well epsilon is not a state, it's a transition. You wouldn't write epsiolon in a vertice but on an edge. It means an empty input. In the context of grammars there aren't really states only terminals and non-terminals. When you have a rule `A -> a` the string stops building because there isn't a new non-terminal (hence terminal <-> terminating). Having a rule `A -> eps` means you add an empty input and you can no longer at anything to it since epsilon is a terminal char.

Comment: I would like to tell you more but the comments are beginning to spam so bundle some questions and create a new question or enter chat. Please also accept the answer!

Comment: Okay one last question regarding this topic.
In your solution of the second part ef*g?
Don't you miss anything? So wouldn't it be correct like this:
Z1->eZ6

   Z1->e

   Z6->fZ7
    Z6->f
   Z6->g 
   Z7-fZ7
   Z7->g

   ?

Comment: No its correct I believe, yours is correct too but not minimal. What string can't you make or which can you make that is invalid?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your last sentence? So my solution isn't wrong?

Comment: No it isn't wrong it's just not optimal. The fewer rules the more optimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type 3 Chomsky are the class of regular grammars constricted to the use of following rules:

```
X -> aY
X -> a,
```

in which X is an arbitrary non-terminal and a an arbitrary terminal. The rule `A -> eps` is only allowed if `A` is not present in any of the right hand sides.

**Construction**

We notice the regular expression consists of two possibilities, either (abc)+d or ef*g?, our first rules will therefor be `S -> aT` and `S -> eP`. These rules allow us to start creating one of the two possibilities. Note that the non-terminals are necessarily different, these are completely different disjunct paths in the corresponding automaton. Next we continue with both regexes separately:

**(abc)+**
We have at least one sequence abc followed by 0 or more occurrences, it's not hard to see we can model this like this:

```
S -> aT
T -> bU
U -> cV
V -> aT   # repeat pattern
V -> d    # finish word
```

**ef*g?** Here we have an e followed by zero or more f characters and an optional g, since we already have the first character (one of the first two rules gave us that), we continue like this:

```
S -> eP
S -> e    # from the starting state we can simply add an 'e' and be done with it,
          # this is an accepted word!
P -> fP   # keep adding f chars to the word
P -> f    # add f and stop, if optional g doesn't occur
P -> g    # stop and add a 'g'
```

**Conclusion**

Put these together and they will form a grammar for the language. I tried to write down the train of thought so you could understand it.

As an exercise, try this regex: (a+b*)?bc(a|b|c)*